# What is causing the blotchy Plot3D

Tags: plotting

```
Plot3D[SoftmaxLayer[][{x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

What is the cause of the blotches on the surface, and of course, how do I get rid of them? [MMA 11.0.1 Win 10 Home, 64-bit, 20H2]

[image]

**Update**

Thanks to @flinty setting Normals-> None produces an inoffensive output.

[image]

Comment: Bad normals on the mesh from [Gouraud shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) maybe. You'll get even more of them, even if you use `PlotPoints -> 25` or more. It's still a problem even using a different engine e.g `Style[Plot3D[...], RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "Mesa"}]`.

Comment: As a workaround, if you use `NormalsFunction -> None` the surface will not look quite as smooth up close but it gets rid of the blotches. You could also supply your own normals.

Comment: Interestingly if you do this: ```softmax[x_, y_] := Exp[{x, y}]/(Exp[x] + Exp[y]);
Plot3D[softmax[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]``` then the plot is fine even with smooth normals, so I suspect there's some numerical trouble with `SoftmaxLayer` derivatives.

Comment: @flinty Thanks... if you want to make it an answer, I can accept immediately. Curious about the alternative form for softmax... I wonder whether some approximation has been used to speed things up for NN processing. And softmax[x_List] := Table[Exp[x[[i]]]/Total@Exp@x, {i, 1, Length[x]}] is considerably faster too.